# How to commit added files only in Eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, git, commit

In Eclipse I'm addding some changed files to the git index. They show up correctly in the *staged changes* tree element. But when I want to commit the changes in the index, the *Commit* action is grayed out.

So, how can I do what `git commit` on the command line would do now. Just commit what has been added earlier.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try and commit through the "Git Repositories" view.

[image: commit or stash]

However, as described in "[Egit Commit](http://wiki.eclipse.org/EGit/User_Guide/Commit)", it will list *all* modified files, staged or not.
(like a `git commit -a`)

Try also the [staged view](http://www.vogella.com/articles/EGit/article.html#usingegit_commitchanges):

[image: staged view]

Comment: Thanks for the hint. Unfortunately I just get a list of all changed files. What I need is just the files added to the index. Sorting the relevant files out again makes the add command useless if you have to manage a lot of files.

Comment: @BetaRide the commit should only commit what is in the index, not *all* the files changed in the worktree.

Comment: @BetaRide http://wiki.eclipse.org/EGit/User_Guide/Commit: I see what you mean: it proposes "Mod., not staged" *and* "Added" files in one list.

Comment: @BetaRide instead of the "Synchronize" view, could you try and use the "Git Staging" view? See my edited answer.

Comment: The "Git Staging" view is the solution for me. Thanks, I didn't discover it until know.